# How to register URL of unusual suffix?

Tags: url

How can I register a URL of format `http://thisneverexist.new`?

Answer (score 0):

Either way you are going to end up paying money to someone, even if only to the registrar of the domain.  Then most likely a DNS provider (and/or a hosting company).  You often get special deals on domain registration from the hosting provider if you host with them for a while - much easier on a beginner.  On the "prefix", you hosting provider will be able to assist in adding additional A-Records for that.